# Keil uVision compiles my code into 0xfff-s

Tags: arm, stm32, keil, stm32f0

I have a weird problem. For some reason, my compiler generates 0xfff-s instead of real code. This happens for a whole file (see screenshot, sim800.c is whole like this), other files are compiled fine.
This does not necessarily happens to this particular file. If I change the code, the sim800.c would compile fine, but some other one would be wrong.
This happens only if optimization if off (`-O0`) If I turn on optimisations (`-O1`) the problem disappears. Clean-compile does not help.

C code along with its assembly

[image]
I'm using

- Keil uVision 5
- GCC v5.06 upd. 1
- STM32F030

Comment: Are you sure the compiler generates FFs ? It looks like the code is not loaded properly (or not at all) to Flash memory, which would explain why the debugger shows only FFs. You should generate a ascii binary file (like .hex or .s19) and check if the binary code is correct or not.

Comment: Yep, it turned out the chip itself erased the code... I have another pice of code that writes info into flash (after erasing whole 1kb page). I specified wrong address, and the chip was writing right in the middle of the code. After optimization the code became smoller and did not reach the specified address.
Feeling like a dumb..
Thanks for your comment =)